# How to debug an SDIO configuration problem?

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, device-tree, sdio

We are trying to get an SDIO-based 802.11 module to work on an SDIO port of the beaglebone. We adapted the device-tree overlay provided by manufacturer to our hardware, compiled the driver, the driver can even be loaded successfully and I see it with `lsmod`, but no interface shows up.

Now I have a missing link in my understanding: How should the driver even know that there is a wifi adapter on SDIO3? The interface used isn't configured anywhere. Shouldn't the system scan the SDIO bus for a device and load the driver matching to the device being found? But `dmesg|grep -i sdio` doesn't even give a match ...

Before closing this question as »too broad«: The question is not about how to fix this problem (that would indeed be too broad), but about how to debug or systematically narrow the cause. What are the steps to test to find out whether the problem is caused on the device-tree side, the kernel module, some glue in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found [this page](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/wi-fi/knowledge-base.entry.html/2019/01/03/linux_sdio_detection-ajSx) which guides me through the basic troubleshooting steps. This was what I was looking for.

If you care for our problem itself: Obviously, muxing the pins as MMC (as described in our user's guide) is not sufficient, the bus needs to be declared as being SDIO in the device-tree. Now I can continue to find out how to enable SDIO detection for the beaglebone.